# javascript Date object create using string from input

Tags: javascript, date

I've got a problem with date object in IE8, and some older browsers. On website I have input hidden, where I keep date, and after change new date should be in that field.

On my machine everything is fine, but on some others I get `NaN-NaN-NaN`, that's my code:

```
var date = new Date($('#curDate').val());
//date.setDate(date.getDate() - 7);
var dateMsg = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
alert(dateMsg);
```

When I run this file (php), in hidden input I've got Monday's date from the current week 2013-03-25.

This alert return me `NaN-N..` on Win XP IE8, and on very old mac, I recon it's problem with object. How to take date value and convert it to object in javascript?

Comment: What date format did you input? Most are not recognised by every browser.

Comment: 2013-03-25 - YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: [date.js](http://www.datejs.com) handles a lot of the cross-browser issues with date parsing, btw..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your hyphens..

> Convert your hyphens('-') with slashes('/')

```
var dateStr=$('#curDate').val();
var a=dateStr.split(" ");
var d=a[0].split("-");
var t=a[1].split(":");
var date = new Date(d[0],(d[1]-1),d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2]);
```

or

```
var date=new Date(convertToSlash($('#curDate').val()));

    function convertToSlash(string){
      var response = string.replace(/-/g,"/");
      return response;
    }
```

Comment: not sensible advice IMHO - converting to "slash" format does not guarantee locale-independent parsing.

Comment: @Alnitak: Dates are nearly always parsed locale-based. To get around that in a cross-browser way, you'd need to use `Date.UTC`

Comment: nb: locales and TZs are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `new Date(some_string)` - it's unreliable because it depends on the user's locale.

Break the string into its `yy/mm/dd` components yourself and then call `new Date(y, m - 1, d)`

Comment: The `Date` constructor uses the local timezone as well.

Comment: @Bergi I wasn't talking about timezone, I was talking about mm/dd/yy vs dd/mm/yy

Comment: Ah, OK. Yet the OP uses YYYY-MM-DD format - which is never YYYY-DD-MM :-)

Comment: his string var uses that, we don't know for certain what's in `#curDate`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use new Date(some_string) format. It's reliable. However, the datestring must be in ISO format that is yyyy/mm/dd.